# C++ Hexadecimal to Decimal Conversion

Tags: c++

I currently have run into an issue that I seem to not understand even while debugging. I am trying to create a hexadecimal to decimal converter program, but I've run into a problem that I can't fix. Every time I try to input 8Fs or higher to convert into decimal, it ends up giving 16Fs' result (aka the max range:18446744....615)

Power Function

```
int powerFunc(int x, int y)
{
    unsigned long long int result = 1;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        result *= x;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Hex to Dec Function

```
int hexToDec(string hexaNumber)
{
    int i;
    int power = hexaNumber.length() - 1;
    int checkLength = hexaNumber.length();
    unsigned long long int decimalResult = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < checkLength; i++) {
        if (int(hexaNumber[i]) >= '0' && int(hexaNumber[i]) <= '9') { // check if FirstHexaNumber 0 to 9
            decimalResult += ((int(hexaNumber[i])) - 48) * powerFunc(16, power); //formula to convert hexadecimal into decimal, int(FirstHexaNumber[i]) is used to convert hexa into a number
        }
        else if (int(hexaNumber[i]) >= 'A' && int(hexaNumber[i]) <= 'F') // check if FirstHexaNumber is A to F
        {
            decimalResult += ((int(hexaNumber[i])) - 55) * powerFunc(16, power);
        }
        else if (int(hexaNumber[i]) >= 'a' && int(hexaNumber[i]) <= 'f') // check if FirstHexaNumber is a to f
        {
            decimalResult += ((int(hexaNumber[i])) - 87) * powerFunc(16, power);
        }
        power--; //power-- since it starts from "HexaNumber.length - 1". Power should decrease as assignment of power goes down
    }

    return decimalResult;
}
```

Main

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long long int result;
    unsigned long long int dec1;
    unsigned long long int dec2;
    unsigned long long int totalDec;
    string hexa1;

    string FirstHexaNumber;

    getline(cin, FirstHexaNumber);

    dec1 = hexToDec(FirstHexaNumber);

    cout << dec1 << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

I have tried debugging the issue, the power function works fine, it manages to get the result it should get. In this case, when I input "FFFFFFFF", the power I get is 268435456, which is correct.

However, when it gets to the converting part, it messes up. For some reason, on the first run on the for loop for the formula, (int(F) - 55) * 16^8 = it ends up giving 18446744....615. 
What can I do to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those `int()` conversions, are they needed? You can safely remove them all, thus have cleaner code.

Comment: Moreover, the  C++ standard library has a power function already: `std::pow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see this line:

```
       decimalResult += ((int(hexaNumber[i])) - 55) * powerFunc(16, power);
```

You get multiplication overflow here. `((int(hexaNumber[i])) - 55)` has the type of `int`. `int` is **at least** from -32767 to 32768, but on 32-bit system where `sizeof(int) = 4` it usually is from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`. `powerFunc(16, power)` int the first iteration is equal to `(int)268435456`. Now for `hexaNumber[i] = 'F'`, you are doing `15 * 268435456` which is `4026531840`. int overflows and because you have wrapped overflow on your machine you get `decimalResult += (int)-268435456`. But `decimalResult` has the type `unsigned long long`, so this number gets converted to unsigned `18446744073441116160`, so after the first loop iteration `decimalResult = 18446744073441116160`.
Probably the simplest fix for your code is to change all types to `unsigned long long`. That means `powerFunc` parameters and return type (you convert `result` in `powerFunc` from int to unsigned long long) and `hexToDec` return value (`hexToDec` return int, yet you return `decimalResult` which is `unsigned long long` and then save the value in `dec1` which is `unsigned long long`).
The good fix is to check for multiplication overflow and handle that case, by for example throwing an exception, like [stoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) throws [out_of_range](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/out_of_range/).
As a side note, you can remove all the `int(...)` conversions and your code will run the same.